# Is it possible to attach activities in gallery view instead of image in android

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, gallery

I have different activies in my project that need to be presented the same way images are displayed in Gallery view. below there should be scroll pan where all these activities are displayed and on clicking on one of them full view is displayed as it is done with image in gallery view. Can any one suggest if this is possible. If yes then give some tutorial link or example code.

Comment: You're confusing terminology but to display navigable views take a look at [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

Comment: I propose this is not possible.  At least, it's not trivially possible and not a good idea either.

Comment: Agree with @David Caunt, `ViewPager` and fragments is the right approach here.

Comment: I tried to use ViewPager code but it is showing me error while importing "import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter; import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;" I included jar file for v4 too and i tried right-clicking on your Android project in Eclipse, choose ‘Android Tools’ and ‘Add Compatibility Library’ but i could not find any such option like add compatibility lib in my project. Plz suggest